# How to let pyautogui recognize popup windows?

Tags: python, windows, popup, screenshot, pyautogui

Apparently, `pyautogui` does not recognize the "real" screen when using the screenshots features.

The following simple code works fine in most cases, but not in all cases.
Apparently, some popup windows will not be recognized (e.g. web pages, Javascript(?), or some Windows messages).

```
import pyautogui

try:
    pyautogui.click('myButtonSomewhereOnTheScreen.png')
    print("Button clicked")
except:
    print("Error: Button not found")
```

[This issue](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/160) has been raised a few years ago but it was stated that it is a limitation in Pillow. Is there maybe any improvement over the years or does someone maybe know of a workaround or a different approach to include such popup windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally pyautogui cannot detect pop-ups, and as you mentioned this is a limitation of the Pillow library. In previous versions we could use pyautogui.locateonscreen but this would cause problems and now only works when the program has already started.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I tried `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()`, in general it is working, but it not recognizing the popup.  I tried to click "OK" on a popup of a web-browser. And even moving with TAB and pressing ENTER does not work. Apparently, I *have* to use the mouse. But it might be difficult if I don't know the position of the OK button. What do you mean with "program has already started"? Which program?

Comment: Obviously, when you run the program before pop-ups, the problem is fixed, which is related to previous versions. Of course, your question is not clear and you did not specify what you want to do it for. If you want to do this to close the popups, you can use the OS commands and other libraries.

Comment: Ok, I guess now I understand.... *my* application has to run already before I start, e.g. the web browser. That's what I did: started my application requested some dummy input, e.g. `input("Press Enter to continue")` to let my program wait, started the other application and now it seems to recognize the OK button of the popup window. Pretty odd. What is the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: The main problem, as you said, is related to Pillow :) Also this library works a bit strangely, I also had these problems in my own projects that I was able to solve with different logics!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for my particular situation.

I could have the popups always consume the whole window.  So when the popup happens, I know that the whole screen x through y is the popup.

So send pyautogui.click() and you will click the popup bringing it to the front (or however you say this)

now with the popup in focus, you can continue your way using pyautogui.locateOnScreen()

I hope that helps someone!  This is the first time I have ever been able to provide a possible answer to something on stack overflow : )